# Customizing the Login Control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a Library Management System using ASP.NET using C#. I have a problem creating a custom login page in my website. I've tried using the ASP.NET Web Configuration but my boss doesnt allow me to install the Aspnet_regsql.exe in the main database.

I have two tables, one table for the username and password and the other one is for the username status (in case the username is deleted or not used anymore). So is there any alternatives or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a separate database for the aspnet login part. This way your boss doesn't have to worry about .NET adding procedures and tables to an existing database. I wouldn't recommend writing your own from scratch as there is always a danger of creating security vulnerabilities that hackers could later exploit.

Comment: Thanks! I could suggest that but I'm still thinking of other alternatives like what if I use locals (since my program will be deployed within the company's private network). We already have the database for the username and password sadly its a sensitive data so they wouldnt let me copy it to a new database with the stored procedure :(

Comment: Thanks! I could use this but I've already have tables for the username and password is there a way where I could direct the calling of username and password from a different database?

Comment: Yes you can :) You just need to create your own custom membership provider. I've not done this myself, but here's some articles from MSDN: [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and [Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think its good idea to implement your own role and membership provider. Its easy, you have to overide just a few methots and create your own view. Try [this](http://mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx) tutorial for start.