# Login Page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry this is actually a repost since my first one wasn't that much satisfactory. I'm making my first program in asp.net. So far everything is ok. I've created a login page using the login control and Membership Provider (using ASP.NET web configuration). I already have the tables for the username and password and since its a sensitive data I cant inject any procedures in it like what the aspnet_regsql.exe does. The question is how can I call the program to use my database of username and password instead of aspnet_* tables? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing the Login Control in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631971/customizing-the-login-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: The answers to the previous question are entirely satisfactory, especially the one with a linked tutorial. Perhaps you should ask a more specific question rather than essentially repeating yourself. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write your own custom `MembershipProvider`.

Comment: Much the same as the answer to his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631971/customizing-the-login-control-in-asp-net/5632340#5632340 I'm voting to close.